# How to test for a Javascript instance and accordingly create an HTML element?

Tags: javascript

I know you can activate Javascript using functions that are linked to HTML code like this:

```
<input type="button" id="foo">
<br>
<script>
    document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("click", thisFunction);
    thisFunction() {
        blah blah blah
    }
</script>
```

Is it possible though, to test for a javascript instance, and then create an HTML element, essentially the reverse? Kind of like this:

```
<script>
    if (i = 0) {
        create HTML header
    }
</script>
```

I'm new to JS and HTML so please don't go crazy if it's a simple response.  Thank you for the help!

full JS:

```
       function myAeroMexicoVacations(cb) {
            aeroMexicoVacationsChecked = cb.checked ? 1 : 0;
            alert(aeroMexicoVacationsChecked + "Aero Mexico Vacations");  
            }
        function myAllInclusiveOutlet(cb) {
            allInclusiveOutletChecked = cb.checked ? 1 : 0;
            alert(allInclusiveOutletChecked + "All Inclusive Outlet");  
            }

        function myBookit(cb) {
            bookitChecked = cb.checked ? 1 : 0;
            alert(bookitChecked + "BookIt");  
            }
        function myCheapCarribean(cb) {
            cheapCarribeanChecked = cb.checked ? 1 : 0;
            alert(cheapCarribeanChecked + "Cheap Carribean");  
            }
        function myCheapTickets(cb) {
            cheapTicketsChecked = cb.checked ? 1 : 0;
            alert(cheapTicketsChecked + "Cheap Tickets");  
            }
        function myDeltaVacations(cb) {
            deltaVacationsChecked = cb.checked ? 1 : 0;
            alert(deltaVacationsChecked + "Delta Vacations");  
            }
        function myExpedia(cb) {
            expediaChecked = cb.checked ? 1 : 0;
            alert(expediaChecked + "Expedia");  
            }
        function myFunJet(cb) {
            funJetChecked = cb.checked ? 1 : 0;
            alert(funJetChecked + "FunJet");  
            }
        function myOrbitz(cb) {
            orbitzChecked = cb.checked ? 1 : 0;
            alert(orbitzChecked + "Orbitz");  
            }
        function myTravelocity(cb) {
            travelocityChecked = cb.checked ? 1 : 0;
            alert(travelocityChecked + "Travelocity");  
        }
        function myUnitedVacations(cb) {
            unitedVacationsChecked = cb.checked ? 1 : 0;
            alert(unitedVacationsChecked + "United Vacations");  
            }
        function myVacationExpress(cb) {
            vacationExpressChecked = cb.checked ? 1 : 0;
            alert(vacationExpressChecked + "Vacation Express");  
            }

        var header = document.createElement('H1');
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
        body[0].appendChild("Hello");
```

Comment: Sounds to me like a "webcomponent"....take a look https://www.webcomponents.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myFunction() { 
  var header = document.createElement('H1');
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('BODY');
  var textnode = document.createTextNode('Hello'); 
  header.appendChild(textnode);
  body[0].appendChild(header); 
}
```

This will tell you what you need to know: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp, or you can use the MDN website, which is also very nice: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.

Comment: How can I activate it and make the H1 show up on the webpage?

Comment: Sorry to bother you so much, but I still don't completely understand. Shouldn't this code then create an html child element? `var header = document.createElement('H1');
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
            body[0].appendChild("Hello");`  I don't see any additional text come up on the webpage though

Comment: @MatthewKaplan yes it should, can you post your full source? That way I can see why it may not be working

Comment: put that code into a function, and then call the function when you need it. If you want to see it work immediately, you can set your document's body onload event to the function: `<body onload="myFunction()">`

Comment: I still don't see "Hello" come up anywhere on the webpage.

Comment: you're appending the string "Hello", not the header element itself. replace "Hello" with the element

Comment: OK, so I replaced "hello" with header, still, nothing comes up.

Comment: did you set the text in the header? I was trying to give you more hints than anything, check the edit

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you so much. Two last questions though. I can do the same with anything else, right? like, <input>? And how can I use CSS on the text?

Comment: As long as the element you are creating is a valid element yes, go to this website, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp, it is a quick read and a great reference for when you have questions like this. And CSS styling using JS is right there as well: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_style.asp